# Using Partial<Type> on a Vue3 reactive() object is acting strangely

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, reactive

I'm facing a weird behavior when using a TypeScript Partial type with a Vue3 reactive object.

I have a simple type representing a User, and need to create a user that may not have some properties at first, so I used a **Partial utility type** :

```js
type User = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

const user_1: Partial<User> = {
  name: 'John'
}

// ✅ Everything's fine here
```

Obviously when I try to put something else in that user, it throws an error :

```js
const user_1: Partial<User> = {
  name: 'John',
  alive: true
  // ❌ Type '{ … }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<User>' […] 'alive' does not exist in type 'Partial<User>'
}
```

This is what I expect from plain TypeScript so no problem here.

But the strange behavior occurs when I try to declare a Vue3 reactive object with that partial :

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const user_2: Partial<User> = reactive({
  id: 42,
  name: 'Gerald',
  alive: true
})
```

Here everything seems to be clear for TypeScript which doesn't yield anything.

What's strange is when I use that `user_2.alive` in the template, the error shows up as expected :

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ user_2.alive }}</h1>
  <!-- ❌ Property 'alive' does not exist on type 'Partial<User>' -->
</template>
```

So, why can't I see the error at the declaration of the reactive object ?
Did I omit something important or could that be a bug in the implementation of TS with reactive()?

> Note: I also tried using the default setup() declaration, in cas of it would be a bug with the  annotation, but the problem still remains

> I could also reproduce the bug on the Vue3 Playground interface here :
> https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: There is a keyword named satisfies for these kind of scenarios

Comment: @Eldar Good to know, thanks. But how can that help with the problem?

Comment: @Eldar I discovered the ˋsatisfies` keyword (didn’t get it at first in your comment because I missed visual formatting, and TS knowledge: apologizes for my previous reply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a type parameter to `reactive` to say that the argument it takes must be of that type:

```
const user_2 = reactive<Partial<User>>({
  id: 42,
  name: 'Gerald',
  alive: true, // ERROR
});
```

Otherwise, it will be inferred automatically. Since excess properties are allowed in assignment (here, assigning returned value from function call to `user_2`), the assignment is allowed.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjJbUgQwomLmEVxIHNMBfTTXBTAB7RMAxREEegGNguAG7QeUAGaJhFKAHIFZCNv4zhJVlDIJEAfQBMqSdLmKIAHgAK9MbnoAbF-CQAPkCACiwcAmIAFhsAGjoSRmYdAHEkX3xteJxfZ2I2fVioAHpiqCQNRF4ASgBuIA)

Comment: I missed out that reactive() could take a type parameter. Totally makes sense to me now with your explaination. Thank you!